# How can == be called if the right hand side is null?

Tags: dart

According to the [docs](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#dont-make-the-parameter-to--nullable):

> The language specifies that null is equal only to itself, and that the == method is called only if the right-hand side is not null.

But I can still do:

```dart
Person? person1;
Person? person2;

void main() {
  print(person1 == person2); // true
  print(Person() == person2); // false
}

class Person {
  @override
  bool operator ==(Object? other) => other != null && other is Person;
}
```

So, who is stopping the invocation of `==` when the objects (`person1` and `person2`) are `null`?

Comment: When you says "who is stopping the invocation", what kind of answer are you looking for in terms of "who"? And what do you mean "when the object is nullable". Which object?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore I mean, why the `==` is not getting called when it is being invoked on a nullable object. The object I'm talking about it `Person? person1`.

Comment: As your quote says, "the == method is called only if the right-hand side is not null". The right-hand side is `null`. And really in this case they're both `null`. So it's calling the `==` method for the Null object.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Alright, but in line `Person() == person2`, which class `==` is getting called, `Null` or `Person`?

Comment: `Person`. It's the same as any other method call. The left-hand side is the object that the method is invoked on.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Perfect, then `==` method in `Person` class should have invoked right, but it doesn't

Comment: Yes. As expected. As your quote says, "the == method is called only if the right-hand side is not null". It would not make sense to invoke `==` if one side is known to be null and the other isn't. It can instead return false immediately

Comment: @ChristopherMoore The question is *why* is that happening? Who is preventing this call?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230898/discussion-between-christopher-moore-and-idecode).

Comment: @Dude Hi, the question wasn't about it. Please give it one more read, I'm asking why `Person` class `==` is not getting invoked when the left hand side is not null but right hand side is. Who is preventing this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Dart Language Tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#equality-and-relational-operators) explains:

> Here’s how the `==` operator works:
>
> 1. If *x* or *y* is null, return true if both are null, and false if only one is null.
> 2. Return the result of the method invocation `x.==(y)`.

If either value in the equality is null, the language automatically checks if both are the `null` object first, before invoking `operator ==`.

Also note that the signature for [`Object.operator ==`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Object/operator_equals.html) is:

```dart
bool operator == (
    Object other
)
```

That is, the argument is guaranteed to be non-nullable.

Comment: This is more clearer than the language used in the Specification guide.

Comment: Sir, should this not show a linter warning or something for `bool operator ==(Object? other)` because `Object?` really makes no sense here.

Comment: You're welcome to [file an issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/linter/issues/) requesting such a lint.

Answer (score 2):

Everything you show is expected behavior. As your quote says, "The language specifies that null is equal only to itself, and that the == method is called only if the right-hand side is not null."

This is defined in the [language spec](https://spec.dart.dev/DartLangSpecDraft.pdf) in the "17.26 Equality" section, which shows how equality is evaluated in Dart:

> Evaluation of an equality expression ee of the form e1 == e2 proceeds
> as follows:
>
> • The expression e1 is evaluated to an object o1.
>
> • The expression e2 is evaluated to an object o2.
>
> • If either o1 or o2 is the null object (17.4), then ee evaluates to
> true if both o1 and o2 are the null object and to false otherwise.
> Otherwise,
>
> • evaluation of ee is equivalent to the method invocation o1.==(o2).

The compiler/VM must implement the spec to be considered Dart. There is no magic here.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. So, in my expression `Person() == person2`, `o1` is `Person` and `o2` is `null`. According to the 3rd point, `o2` is `null` so the ee should evaluate to `true` but actually it prints `false`. Correct me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: @iDecode No, reread the third point: "ee evaluates to true if **both** o1 and o2 are the null object and false otherwise".

Comment: @iDecode It says "evaluates to true *if both o1 and o2 are the null* object"

Comment: @jamesdlin I think I need to work on my English first, I read the sentence like this "If either o1 or o2 is the null object (17.4), then ee evaluates to true *and* if both o1 and o2 are the null object to false otherwise".

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Hey, James's answer is little more easy to understand, so I'm accepting his. Although I'll upvote yours too. Thanks for your help!